# Project a shapely geometry over a linestring

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, shapely, linestring

I'm looking for the most exact way to project a shapely polygon over a line.

I assume that any projected point of the polygon is inside the linestring.

My first idea is to densify the boundary of the polygon (e.g. every 100m) and use [object.project](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.project) to project all this vertices over the line.

The above solution could introduce a slight approximation error.

Is there an exact solution or a better way to do this calculation?

Comment: FYI a way to project a point over a generic linestring is already approached here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061521/projection-of-a-point-to-a-line-segment-python-shapely

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough solution based on projection of densified vertices.
It is an approximate and not very efficient solution.
Any other solution is welcome.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString

def project_shape_over_centerline(
    shape: Polygon,
    centerline: LineString,
    step: float = 500
) -> LineString:
    """
    Project a shape along a linestring. The algorith densify border of the shape every 1000m and reproject it
    along the line. This could give a rough approximation (depending on densification step) of the projection
    of the shape.

    This funcion make the following assumptions:
        - centerline is a almost stright line (e.g. no zig-zag, no loops, etc etc)
        - every projected point is inside centerline (e.g. centerline is wider than projected shape)
        - all coordinates are projected and in the same CRS

    Parameters:
    -----------
    shape (Polygon): shape to project over the centerline
    centerline (LineString): The linestring over reproject the shape
    step (float): densification step in meter

    Returns:
    --------
    projected_shape (LineString): The projection of densified vertices over centerline
    """
    boundary = shape.boundary
    max_length = boundary.length

    projected_points = []
    distance = 0
    while distance < max_length:
        vertex = boundary.interpolate(distance)
        projected_distance = centerline.project(vertex)
        projected_point = centerline.interpolate(projected_distance)
        projected_points.append(projected_point)
        # calc the next densified point
        distance += step

    projected_shape = LineString(projected_points)
    return projected_shape
```